# How to make Keras use Tensorflow backend in Anaconda?

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, backend, keras

I have install tensorflow-gpu in my Anaconda environment. They both work well.

Now I am trying to install Keras with Tensorflow backend. According to the [instruction](https://keras.io/#installation) I just run:

```
pip install keras
```

But it doesn't install keras, then I tried:

```
conda install -c conda-forge keras=2.0.2
```

Then I am now able import keras in python. But the problem is, it always use the Theano backend. I am trying to change this, but not knowing how to do it.

I also tried edit the file **~/.keras**, but actually default backend was tensorflow already.

Please help.. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This happens because the keras conda-forge package puts a file in `${CONDA_PREFIX}/etc/conda/activate.d/keras_activate.sh`, which sets the environment variable `KERAS_BACKEND`

```
(root) [root@starlabs ~]# cat $CONDA_PREFIX/etc/conda/activate.d/keras_activate.sh
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$(uname)" == "Darwin" ]
then
    # for Mac OSX
    export KERAS_BACKEND=tensorflow
elif [ "$(uname)" == "Linux" ]
then
    # for Linux
    export KERAS_BACKEND=theano
fi
```

As you can see from the file, in Linux, it sets the value to 'theano' and according to the official docs:

> the environment variable KERAS_BACKEND will override what is
>   defined in your config file

To work around this, you can either edit this file and change 'theano' to 'tensorflow' (which would probably get overwritten on reinstall or on changing environments) or, do the following:

```
export KERAS_BACKEND=tensorflow
python /path/to/python/program.py
```

Comment: Hi @nehal, thank you! The work-around method you said is working. But I am trying to find the keras_activate.sh. However there is no **conda/** in **${CONDA_PREFIX}/etc/**. This is my ls: `dbus-1/  fish/    fonts/   jupyter/ rc.d/`

Comment: @TaiChristian Search for keras_activate.sh . `find $CONDA_PREFIX | grep keras_activate.sh`

Comment: Just noting for lost souls that this applies to Windows as well, but your commands are "echo %CONDA_PREFIX%" and "set KERAS_BACKEND=tensorflow".

Comment: Would `os.environ['KERAS_BACKEND'] = 'tensorflow'` (before importing `keras`) also work?

Comment: @BallpointBen Probably, but you will have to do it before importing keras

Answer (score 10):

Had the same problem after installing keras from conda-forge. `keras.json` already had tensorflow:

```
{
    "floatx": "float32",
    "epsilon": 1e-07,
    "backend": "tensorflow",
    "image_data_format": "channels_last"
}
```

but `activate tensorflow_keras`  (where "`tensorflow_keras`" is the environment name), changes the backend to theano:

```
C:\Users\User1>activate tensorflow_keras

(tensorflow_keras) C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_keras\etc\conda\ac
tivate.d>set "KERAS_BACKEND=theano"
```

Following @FvD above, I edited this file:

```
C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_keras\etc\conda\activate.d
```

and changed theano to tensorflow:

```
set "KERAS_BACKEND=tensorflow"
```

Comment: Thank you! Could be the answer for people who use Windows :3

Answer (score 4):

On a multi-user install on Windows 10 the Anaconda environment activation file is:

```
C:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\<environment name>\etc\conda\activate.d\keras_activate.bat
```

Just change `<user name>` and `<environment name>` to match.

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar problem, seems that if `~/.keras/keras.json` is not accessible, keras is using `/tmp/.keras/keras.json`

Answer (score 1):

For Windows users using Anaconda. Open the Anaconda Prompt and type:

```
set "KERAS_BACKEND=tensorflow"
```

That should do the trick.
If using Jupyter Notebook, you would need to restart it.

Answer (score 0):

Though this seems a bit of work, if you use conda envs as much as I do , where I have environments for Tensorflow and Theano separately. It will reduce a lot of repeated setting and unsetting of environment variables each time it is activated.

https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html

According to conda envs page.

1)Locate the directory for the conda environment in your Terminal window, such as

```
/home/jsmith/anaconda3/envs/analytics.
```

2)Enter that directory and create these subdirectories and files:

```
cd /home/jsmith/anaconda3/envs/analytics
mkdir -p ./etc/conda/activate.d
mkdir -p ./etc/conda/deactivate.d
touch ./etc/conda/activate.d/env_vars.sh
touch ./etc/conda/deactivate.d/env_vars.sh
```

3)Edit ./etc/conda/activate.d/env_vars.sh as follows:

```
echo 'export KERAS_BACKEND=theano' > ./etc/conda/activate.d/env_vars.sh
```

4)Edit ./etc/conda/deactivate.d/env_vars.sh as follows:

```
echo 'unset KERAS_BACKEND' > ./etc/conda/deactivate.d/env_vars.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

In Mac system, go to terminal and navigate to user profile and check whether **.keras** folder exists or not.

```
ls -a
cd .keras
vim keras.json # edit the keras.json file in editor and change the backend to tensorflow
```

*It should look like this.*

```
"floatx": "float32",
"epsilon": 1e-07,
"backend": "tensorflow",
"image_data_format": "channels_last"
```

Close the Editor by pressing **escape** button then follwed by **:wq**
It should work

Now if you are using any conda environment then follow below mentioned steps
1. first locate the environment variable by navigating to the anaconda env folder

**Anaconda3/envs/"name_of_your_conda_environment"/etc/conda/activate.d**

It contains the file keras_activate.bat which has **theano as** backend by default.
Change the value to tensorflow and save the file.
**KERAS_BACKEND=tensorflow**

deactivate the environment and activate it again 
i.e

```
source deactivate name_of_your_conda_environment
source activate name_of_your_conda_environment
```

Hope this will solve all keras backend tensorflow issues.

Answer (score 0):

**For Windows users**, in my case Windows 10 it seems that how Anaconda creates the .bat files is a bit strange, or at least how they are being executed. They show every command written, in them in the cmd.
At least in my case that is.
So for me it always said: `"KERAS_BACKEND=theano"`, but that was not executed.
*Check this:*
In this path: `<your_conda_install_location>\envs\<your_environment_name>\etc\conda\activate.d`
you'll find a `.bat` file.
(replace `<whatever>` in path references I make with your system specific names)
*also check* whether the `keras.json` file has the backend set to tensorflow.
The content in mine was:

```
:: Figure out the default Keras backend by reading the config file.
python %CONDA_PREFIX%\etc\keras\load_config.py > temp.txt
set /p KERAS_BACKEND=<temp.txt
del temp.txt

:: Try to use the default Keras backend.
:: Fallback to Theano if it fails (Theano always works).
python -c "import keras" 1> nul 2>&1
if errorlevel 1 (
    ver > nul
    set "KERAS_BACKEND=theano"
    python -c "import keras" 1> nul 2>&1
)
```

I simply added `@echo off` so it doesn't show all the code and added some console output to tell me what was actually executed. That simultaneously works as kind of a debugger or proof that it actually did not execute `set "KERAS_BACKEND=theano"`
(scroll down to see the full edited `.bat` file)
on top I added:

```
@echo off
:: message variables
set er0=used default Keras backend tensorflow
set er1=used fallback Keras backend theano
```

for the messages:
at the end of `:: Figure out the default Keras backend by reading the config file.`:

```
if errorlevel 0 (
    echo %er0%
    )
```

inside the if from `:: Fallback to Theano if it fails (Theano always works)`:

```
echo %er1%
```

And now the **complete code** of the `.bat` for a better overview:

```
@echo off
:: message variables
set er0=used default Keras backend tensorflow
set er1=used fallback Keras backend theano

:: Figure out the default Keras backend by reading the config file.
python %CONDA_PREFIX%\etc\keras\load_config.py > temp.txt
set /p KERAS_BACKEND=<temp.txt
del temp.txt
if errorlevel 0 (
    echo %er0%
    )

:: Try to use the default Keras backend.
:: Fallback to Theano if it fails (Theano always works).
python -c "import keras" 1> nul 2>&1
if errorlevel 1 (
    ver > nul
    set "KERAS_BACKEND=theano"
    echo %er1%
    python -c "import keras" 1> nul 2>&1
)
```

So now there are only messages on the cmd which state if the default backend was used or if in case of an error it used the theano backend.
Also *make sure to check* that the `keras.json` has the backend set to tensorflow.
I hope this helps some windows users.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot explicitly call
 `import keras`.
 Use:

> `import tensorflow as tf`

Now you can use:

`tf.keras`

Answer (score -2):

There is a file `keras_activate.sh` in the path `"/anaconda2/envs/py2/etc/conda/activate.d"`.

Then editing it, delete the content :

```
"if [ "$(uname)" == "Darwin" ]
```

then

```
    # for Mac OSX
    export KERAS_BACKEND=tensorflow
elif [ "$(uname)" == "Linux" ]
```

then

```
    # for Linux
    export KERAS_BACKEND=theano
fi".
```

after that, add the line :

```
set "KERAS_BACKEND=tensorflow"
```

Answer (score -3):

First of all you have to install one of the following python versions

Then install tensor flow as the backend engine using the following command:

```
pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow
```

Then install keras using the following command:

```
pip3 install keras
```

More information available here: http://royalcrowntutorials.blogspot.com/2018/02/installing-tensor-flow-start-terminal.html